# Load different URLs based on different UITableViewCell clicks-iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm new to iOS and its developing. I'm developing iPhone application.there i have `UITableView` and `UIWebView`. When i am pressing `UITableview`'s cell, according to click there i want to load various webpages in my `UIWebView`. how do i do it.please help me

for an example

```
cell-one of tableview --> web page 1 in UIWebView
cell-two of tableview --> web page 2 in UIWebView
```

**But in my application, all the cells redirect to one web page.please find below the code i used.**

tabelViewcontroller.m

```
![@interface Essentialinfocontroller ()
{

    NSMutableArray * titlearray;

    NSMutableArray * subtitilearray;

}
@end

@implementation Essentialinfocontroller

@synthesize info;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    \[super viewDidLoad\];
    self.info.delegate=self;
    self.info.dataSource=self;

    titlearray =\[\[NSMutableArray alloc\]initWithObjects:@"Custom",@"Department Of Immigration",@"Foriegn Currency Regulations",@"Sri Lankan Embassies" ,@"Sri Lankan Visa",@"When You Are There..", nil\];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return \[titlearray count\];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString * cellidentifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell=

    \[info dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath\];

    cell.textLabel.text =\[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row\];

    return cell;



}



-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if(\[segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"custom"\])
    {


    }
}


@end][1]
```

detailviewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.lk"];
    NSURLRequest * requestURL= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [webView  loadRequest:requestURL];


}
```

Comment: So you want to load different URLs based on different cell row clicks ?

Comment: @iCoder yes thats all i want

Comment: Well why don't you do all stuff in viewDidLoad also in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:? Depend on indexPath.row you can load different webView content.

Comment: You are using a constant url in ViewDidLoad Method, Please make it dynamic according to selection of tableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do , First implement the following method in your tableViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sender:self];
}
```

And then your prepareForSegue Method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"custom"]) {
      detailViewController.urlString = @"Your Custom Url";
    } else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Department Of Immigration"]){
    detailViewController.urlString = @"Your Department Of Immigration Url";
    }
}
```

And Then in DetailViewController.h
Add the following property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *urlString;
```

And in DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
    NSURLRequest * requestURL= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView  loadRequest:requestURL];
}
```

Comment: You will end up with a big if else if ladder in `prepareforsegue` if number of cells are more.

Answer (score 0):

From the code shown above it looks like you have not implemented `UITableViewDelegate` methods. In particular `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will inform you the particular row clicked. Based on this you can set URL in the `DetailViewController` and load different URLs for each cell click.

Create an array `myURLList` which will have all the URLs corresponding to your Table Cells first.

Set your ViewController as `UITableView` delegate and implement below method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.webURL = [myURLList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Create a Property Web URL in View Controller and update based on Cell Selection.
}
```

In prepare for segue: (assuming your views are embedded in Navigation Controllers)

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)navController.topViewController;
controller.selectedURL = self.webURL; // In DetailViewController, create a Property as `selectedURL`
```

In DetailViewContrlloler modify viewDidLoad to pick up URL from the property `selectedURl`

Comment: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate i have used it in my header file

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Array of all your URL's.
2. Use `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to identify which row is clicked. In this delegate method `indexPath.row` will give you the index of the row which is called.
3. Then in your `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` function send the desire URL.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you will have to send the appropriate URL from the source Controller itself. You can try it like this :

1. Take a `NSString` property (say `goToURL`)in the .h file of your TableViewController. Now in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, depending on which row jus tapped, you can give the URL value to that property we declared.
2. Now in your DestinationViewController, take a property variable and in your prepareForSegue method, set the value of that variable to the value that we assigned to the previous variable. Something like this :

   DetailViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];

   ```
   destController.URLvar= _goToURL;
   ```
3. So now when your DetailViewController will show up, you will have a URL value in the `URLvar` variable which you can then use to load up your web view.